# If $f$ is $C^1(\mathbb{R})$, is it $C^1(\{a\})$?

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, continuity

Say I have a well-behaved function like $f(x)=x$. This is obviously $C^1$, but does it make sense to say the function is $C^1$ around a single point? A broader question, if $a\in\mathbb{R}$, does there exist a real-valued function $f$ such that $f\in C^1[\{a\}]$?

I am having a hard time understanding if the concept is not well-defined or if the definition holds vacuously. For continuity at least, it seems like the sequential definition holds since every sequence $\{x_n\}$ on this set would just have $x_i=a$ for any $i\in\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: Generally we only talk about derivatives of functions on open sets. How would you define the derivative of a function that has a single point in its domain?

Comment: Maybe the derivative exists in an open neighbourhood of $x=a$ but it is continuous only in $x=a$. In such a peculiar situation, to state that $f\in C^1(\{a\})$ makes sense, to me.

Answer (score 0):

Differentiability is a local concept, so if you say that a function is diferentiable in a point is possible, since you define de derivative as the clasic limite,  when the limite exists. When you consider  limite process, you just look to the function in a little neighborhood of the point. If you define a function on a single point, (i.e $f:\{a\}\to \mathbb{R}$), then this function is automatically continuous, diferentiable, since it is constante, it has no variation. Any doubt, coment this answer.